# Display the definition of each items in beamer one by one using onslide or any method

Tags: beamer, itemize

I have three items in a slide and there is one block where I would like to show the definition of each items. On each click or button press I want to change the item name and the corresponding definition. I was able to do this for the graphics, but I was not able to achieve this effect for the text.

The sample tex document is as follows:

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer} 

% Setup appearance:

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[ball]
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\usecolortheme[RGB={205,173,0}]{structure} 
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
\useoutertheme{infolines} 

%Pacakges
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphics}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\mode<presentation>{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Motivation}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> Travel time 
        \item<2-> Residence time
        \item<3-> Biology
    \end{itemize}

    \begin{block}{Definition}
        <1> {Travel time is the time required by the particle to move from one point to another point.}
        <2> {Residence time is the time required for the particle to get out of the system.}
        <3> {Biology is the study of living things.}
    \end{block} 

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use `\only<overlay specification>`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[ball]
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\usecolortheme[RGB={205,173,0}]{structure}
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

%Packages
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphics}

\mode<presentation>{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Motivation}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item Travel time
        \item Residence time
        \item Biology
    \end{itemize}

    \begin{block}{Definition}
        \only<1>{Travel time is the time required by the particle to move from one point to another point.}
        \only<2>{Residence time is the time required for the particle to get out of the system.}
        \only<3>{Biology is the study of living things.}
    \end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: animation showing how the definition box changes content for each item]

Change to `\only<1->`, `\only<2->`,... if you want the description to appear cumulatively.

Answer (score 11):

You could just wrap the entries within your `Definition` block in an `itemize` the same way you did for the regular `itemize` entries frame. That would "bullet" the definition list, but might be what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer} % http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer

% Setup appearance:

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[ball]
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\usecolortheme[RGB={205,173,0}]{structure} 
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
\useoutertheme{infolines} 

\mode<presentation>{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Motivation}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item<1-> Travel time 
    \item<2-> Residence time
    \item<3-> Biology
  \end{itemize}

  \begin{block}{Definition}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item<1-> Travel time is the time required by the particle to move from one point to another point.
      \item<2-> Residence time is the time required for the particle to get out of the system.
      \item<3-> Biology is the study of living things.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The above avoids a vertical skipping across frames due to different text lengths in your `Definition` block.