# In beamer, create a new slide for every item of a list

Tags: beamer, lists, enumerate

In a beamer class document, I would like to change the definition of the enumerate environment in such a way that every item is displayed in its own frame, at the top of the frame. In other words, I would like the following code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% Code changing the definition of enumerate
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First point
  \item Second point
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

to produce the same result than

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
1) First point
\vspace*{\textheight} % moves the item at the top of the slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
2) Second point
\vspace*{\textheight}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note that I do not want the `1) First point` to appear on the second slide.

If it is possible (cherry on the cake!), I would like this redefinition of `enumerate` to be applied only when used inside a certain environment (say `myenv`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<only@1>` to show a particular item on the first slide of a frame only. Instead of `\vspace*{\textheight}`. use `[t]` in order to top align the contents of a frame:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{enumerate}
 \item<only@1> First point
 \item<only@2> Second point
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! But you do not answer my question, as I want the behavior of \item to be modified once and for all, and not having to type <only@n> to every item

Comment: @Guillaume maybe this answer helps you, if you have still the same problem? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116922/261918

Comment: Thanks for proposing but is is not helpful here: the answer you link to proposes to use "only", which is roughly what this answer by leandriis proposed.