# Beamer: how to display item one at a time BUT also hide the first item

Tags: beamer, itemize, presentations

There are many answers as to how to show item one item at a time in Beamer
[Display the definition of each items in beamer one by one using onslide or any method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116913/display-the-definition-of-each-items-in-beamer-one-by-one-using-onslide-or-any-m)

But these answers do not address the case where I want to hide the first item as well (start with a completely blank slate).

The first item is always displayed when you use the following code.

```
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
 ...
\end{itemize}
```

I tried to put it in a \only<> block. However, this causes the itemize to display two items simultaneously.

Is there anyway to address this problem?

Comment: There are [a number of options](https://pastebin.com/raw/MwLWrNm3). However, using `[<+(1)->]` as the overlay specification is probably what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to achieve this is by adding a `\pause` before `\begin{itemize}`.