# What is the most efficient way to have text appear on click in beamer?

Tags: animations

So I want to create a presentation where each bullet point appears on click as in PowerPoint. I've seen a variety of solutions including the

```
\break
```

Command.

Here's a sample of the code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\uncover<1->{\item Hi}
\uncover<2->{\item Hello}
\uncover<3->{\item Hi again}
\uncover<4->{\item Hello again}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this i.e. can I do it so that it doesn't create individual slides?

Comment: Have a look at Werner's comment here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/585084/238121

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options. In list environments like `enumerate` the perhaps easiest one is to add `[<+->]`. You can also use `\pause` but then one may want to topalign the contents to avoid jumps (which generally looks better).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The use of \texttt{<+->}}
\begin{enumerate}[<+->]
 \item Hi
 \item Hello
 \item Hi again
 \item Hello again
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{The use of \texttt{<+->} and \texttt{t}}
\begin{enumerate}[<+->]
 \item Hi
 \item Hello
 \item Hi again
 \item Hello again
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{The use of \texttt{\textbackslash pause} and \texttt{t}}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item Hi\pause
 \item Hello\pause
 \item Hi again\pause
 \item Hello again
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]